# How to make ui slider to control jQuery.fx.interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a website using a lot of animations but I have to limit the animations to jQuery.fx.interval = 100; so the CPU isn't maxed out at 100%. Since the animation speeds are slower, I was wondering is their a way that I can have a slider on my page so any user can control jQuery.fx.interval either by sliding it higher or lowering it to 0?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

How do I add

```
jQuery.fx.interval = 100;
```

To This

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 100,
        min: 0,
        max: 700,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ));
});
```

animation for background, used with jQuery backgroundPosition plugin.
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect

```
$(function(){
    $('body').animate({backgroundPosition:"(-99999px 0)"}, 6000000, 'linear');
    $('html').animate({backgroundPosition:"(-99999px -100000px)"}, 12000000, 'linear');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To make things easier, you can use this plugin:
https://github.com/lrbabe/jquery.updateInterval

Then you can just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $( "#slider" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 100,
        min: 0,
        max: 700,
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).html( ui.value );
            $.fx.updateInterval(ui.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Notice that:

> Since jQuery uses one global interval, no animation should be running or all animations should stop for the change of this property to take effect.
>   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/

Comment: hmmm... it doesn't work. So do I need to incorporate jQuery.fx.off some how?

Comment: You know that if you reload the page, the previous slider value is lost and so is the jQuery.fx.interval value, right?

Is the animation always "running"? You should stop the animation and restart it so that the new value is used.

Comment: you right, I got store it into a cookie. The animation that I have that's always running is the background. I have two backgrounds moving in the same direction with different speeds so it gives a parallax effect.

Comment: ok, so before jQuery.fx.interval = ui.value; you have to stop animations and after it restart them. I added the code that stops all animations in the page. You have to add the start animation code yourself :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but i'm a noob with jQuery, so how do I start all animations again?

Comment: I don't think there is any easy way. you have to set the effects again. How are you starting them in the first place? just repeat that

Comment: I tried adding my code like you said but no luck. Mabye im doing something wrong. Anyways, I updated my top post with the animation that's always running.